# Trying to capture photos using an existing camera application. (App crashes)

Tags: android

I'm using the google documention a
thttp://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html 
to allow my app to capture pictures.  The app worcked fine when I just called up the camera.  When I added the code to capture the image,
 it would crash, and then the camera app would run.

This is the code

```
public void onClick(View v){
    super.onClick(v);    

    Intent i;  
    Intent browserIntent;

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.butTakePhoto:
            // call the camera
            Intent takePictureIntent = 
                  new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);

           // capture image from camera
           // this code causes it to crash
           Bundle extras = takePictureIntent.getExtras();
           Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
           mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);

           break;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get the data from the intent here.

Once you call `startActivityForResult()`, your app goes into its `paused` state, while the new activity is brought to the foreground.

You are calling start activity for result, which means that when the camera activity finishes, you will get a result here.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
}
```